# prevent opening safari in cordova webview links

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

In my cordova app I just open an external website as the content src:

```
<content src="http://example.com" />
```

When linking inside my website with normal links:

```
<a href='/internal.html' />
```

it opens external safari browser and not staying inside the app.
I've managed to achieve staying inside the app by using this code:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='window.open("/internal.html","_self")'></a>
```

Is there a way to stay HTML native without javascript and link inside the app?

Comment: Sounds strange. I usually use commands like this <a href='tour.html'></a> without problems, they are opened inside the app.